# Testing Java, Separating Test Class and Main method - not using Junit

Tags: java, testing

Sorry, I am not understanding something fundamental.  If I run the code below as a single program I get the correct result.  But I want to separate out my method and main method into a test program and then I get the errors: petName cannot be resolved into a variable, yearBorn cannot be resolved into a variable and the method print() is undefined for HousePet(). I try addressing those by defining them locally and get new errors. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Code that works:

```
package simplequestion;

public class HousePet2 {
    public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "Zz$$$";
    public static final int DEFAULT_YEARBORN = 2021;
    private String petName;
    private int yearBorn;

    public HousePet2() {
        petName = DEFAULT_NAME;
        yearBorn = DEFAULT_YEARBORN;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Name = " + petName);
        System.out.println("Year Born = " + yearBorn);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new HousePet2().print();
    }
}
```

Code that doest work:

```
package simplequestion;

public class HousePet {
    public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "Zz$$$";
    public static final int DEFAULT_YEARBORN = 2021;
    private String petName;
    private int yearBorn;

    public HousePet() {
        petName = DEFAULT_NAME;
        yearBorn = DEFAULT_YEARBORN;
    }
}

package simplequestion;

public class TestQuest {

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Name = " + petName);
        System.out.println("Year Born = " + yearBorn);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new HousePet().print();
    }
}
```

If I try the following I get variables cannot be resolved:

```
package simplequestion;

public class TestQuest {


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        HousePet pet1 = new HousePet();
        pet1.System.out.println("Name = " + petName);
        pet1.System.out.println("Name = " + yearBorn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `TestQuest` class is trying to use `petName` and `yearBorn` in its `print` method, but those are private instance variables of the `HousePet` class, so not accessible by `TestQuest`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the correct set and get as follows:

```
package simplequestion;

public class HousePet {
    public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "Zz$$$";
    public static final int DEFAULT_YEARBORN = 2021;
    private String petName;
    private int yearBorn;

    public HousePet() {
        petName = DEFAULT_NAME;
        yearBorn = DEFAULT_YEARBORN;
    }
    
    public void setPetName (String name) {
        this.petName = name;
    }
    public String getPetName () {
        return petName;
    }
    
    public void setYearBorn (int born) {
        this.yearBorn = born;
    }
    public int getYearBorn () {
        return yearBorn;
    }

}

package simplequestion;

public class TestQuest {


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        HousePet pet1 = new HousePet();
        System.out.println("Name = " + pet1.getPetName());
        System.out.println("Name = " + pet1.getYearBorn());
    }
```

}